# Deleting tail of linked list: Why a specific approach won't work

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am trying to understand why a certain function will delete the tail of the linked list as opposed to another.

This is my linked list struct:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;
```

My implementation of tail insert:

```
node *tail_insert(node *head, int data)
{
    node *temp;

    if (head == NULL)
        return create_doubly_node(data);

    for (temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        ;

    temp->next = create_doubly_node(data);
    temp->next->prev = temp->next;

    return head;

}
```

This function deletes the tail:

```
node *tail_delete(node *head)
{
    node *temp, *prev;

    if (head == NULL)
        return head;

    temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    free(temp);
    prev->next = NULL;

    return head;
}
```

As opposed to this one:

```
node *tail_delete(node *head)
{
    node *temp, *prev;

    if (head == NULL)
        return head;

    temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    prev = temp->prev;
    free(temp);
    prev->next = NULL;

    return head;
}
```

The difference being present in how I assign node *prev.

Comment: did you check is your linked list maintains the pointer `prev` correctly?

Comment: My node *prev was set to the current node, not the actual previous node. Thank you.

Comment: Hi As you said that your prev node is pointing to current node that is not a proper doubly link list. That means prev is pointing to itself and both function will behave differently. In first delete method prev will point to previous node of last node and in the second method both prev and temp are pointing to same node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your below statement is wrong for which your second method is not working as your prev pointer is pointing to a wrong node:-

```
temp->next->prev = temp->next; //here prev is pointing to itself
                               //actually prev = create_doubly_node(data);
```

correct it to:-

```
 temp->next->prev = temp; //as temp is pointing to the previous node of last node
```